# is this possible in re in python?

Tags: python, regex

In regular expression in python

`[abc]` matches either a or b or c

How to do `[abc]` that matches either ab or bc ? Is this possible ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `|` regular expression operator to specify multiple possibilities:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile("ab|bc")
>>>
>>> print pattern.match("abbbb")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x105117918>
>>> print pattern.match("fooo")
None
>>> print pattern.match("bcdd")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x105117918>
>>> print pattern.match("abc")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x105117918>
```

Wrap them in brackets if it's part of a larger expression:

```
>>> pattern = re.compile("(red|green) light")
>>> print pattern.match("red light")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x105117918>
>>> print pattern.match("red lights everywhere")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1051116c0>
>>> print pattern.match("green lights forever")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x105117918>
>>> print pattern.match("blue lights begone")
None
```

See [regular expression syntax](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) in the Python documentation for all of the options.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i want to know whether can i do it using '[]' Currently [] matches a single charecter but isnt it possible to do the same for string ? like  ['ab','bc','cd']

Comment: @ynwa No. `[]` always represents a set of possibilities for a single character. It can't be used for this kind of restriction.

Comment: No, it's not. [] is the character grouping operand, why do you insist doing something else with it?

Comment: @teukkam for input 1) xyz@gmail.com and 2)xyzatabc.com, the regex should match both, i am thinking like re.findall(r'([\w\.-]*)([@|at])([\w\.-]*)', str)

Comment: @ynwa just remove the square brackets `([\w\.-]*)(@|at)([\w\.-]*)`, see it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?30f4d)

Answer (score 1):

`[abc]` is called a **[character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)**. It matches one out of the character set given between the square brackets. This is fine for single characters, but will not work for character sequences.

For a character sequence you need an **[alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)**, this looks like `a|b|c`. This would be equivalent to `[abc]`, but now you can put in sequences.

```
ab|bc
```

would match either "ab" **or** "bc"

If the alternation is part of a larger expression you need to group it together

```
(?:ab|bc)
```

`(?:...)` is a [non capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), it will not capture the matched sub-pattern.